# Link static Qt library to c program

Tags: c++, c, qt, gcc, static-linking

I am in the need to link against a library (written in Qt by myself). Of course this would generate (regardless of the `extern "C"` and name mangling stuff) a lot of errors during linking because of the C++ dependencies (stdc++ *and* Qt).

So I have got an idea, but I'm not sure, if I am missing something or if the approach is a realistic solution at all:

Searching some hints on this topic, I have found an article about [building static Qt](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_Qt_on_Linux). Without reading all of it in detail I think the solution could be to compile Qt statically and then link my application against this static version of Qt. In my opinion this should lead to a successful build because of the following reasons:

1. Building my Qt library with the static Qt Library (again as static lib) would resolve all dependencies because they are all in the static lib archive.
2. Because of the `extern "C"`d interface functions, that will be accessed by the c application the C compiler (and linker) will also see all dependencies resolved and here is no problem either.

Now before trying the exhausting steps to build Qt statically, I would like to know, whether this approach *could* solve the problem.

EDIT 1:
The alternative solution would be to implement a server-client architecture on top of both the Qt- and the C-part of the application and let them communicate in that way with each other.

EDIT 2:
The probably best solution is neither of the both mentioned. Instead I just wrote a dynamically linked boundary (as suggested by Laszlo Papp and dsu) and everything works fine.

Comment: Generally i would agrree with your assumption, but you will need a commercial license of Qt or open source your library (and the application if linked statically to your library). Also building Qt for static linking can be a pain in the a... depending on your needs (plugins/SSL/etc.). Do not forget that creating a statically linked app or library will boost the size dramatically, less than providing all DLLs but still enough to give a stressful download for low-bandwith connections.

Comment: I just forgot one of the main points not to do so, upgrading the application, library or Qt always requires you to deploy the whole installation again, instead of only updating the shared-linked-application.

Comment: I am not sure how this could work. You mean you would write an adapter between your software and Qt establishing the proper ABI?

Comment: @LaszloPapp The existing Qt code will be extended so that it provides functions that can be called from the C code. So there will be an init function, for example, some getters and setters probably and so on. Am I ignoring something important?

Comment: @exilit: OK, are you a commercial customer of Digia?

Comment: can't you just use g++ as the linker for the c part? or are you bound to the c linker? building qt is horrible, so i would try to avoid that...

Comment: @LaszloPapp I already realised the license problems after Sebastian Lange has commented on the question.

Comment: @dsu No, this is not an option, I am bound to the c linker.

Comment: @exilit: is your code open-sourceable?

Comment: @LaszloPapp No, it is not. And I actually just wanted some pointers regarding the mentioned idea/solution.

Comment: anyway... it should be doable to link all that together. i just played around a bit and this works: http://89.238.76.97/david/linking_fun.tar.gz maybe you can try plugging some qt function in these cpp files and see if it works... (just forget about the extern C in the cpp_boundary.h. thats wrong.)

Comment: @dsu Thank you for the example. I tried to adopt it to link against the Qt stuff but there are unresolved dependencies to Qt core functions (libQt5Core.so.5) during the linkage of the main program (some_c_program) and I cannot figure out why. If you could post your comment as an answer I would like to discuss that.

Comment: @dsu Thanks again for your comment. I got it running now. That were just configuration issues. After telling the linker the path to the libraries everything went well. I will experiment a little bit and if needed I will post the solution afterwards.

Comment: @exilit: hey nice - im glad that it works for you =D. have fun with your project.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Maybe you are right, but I think it could be a helpful hint anyway, couldn't it? I would have liked to see such an example or at least some rough explanation.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I am not in doubt anymore. But I had some problems during linking because the linker didn't knew the library path. But this is special to my Qt installation and if I look at the current makefile now, I realize that there is indeed no other magic than this few linking flags...

Comment: @exilit: yeah, it is the same way, great. You can also specify the full path to the static library which is not done for dynamic libraries, but yeah, other than that, it is the same process. This will also help reducing your application size, and updating Qt without re-deploying your software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now before trying the exhausting steps to build Qt statically, I would like to know, whether this approach could solve the problem.

Based on the comments where you mention that becoming a commercial client of Digia is a problem, I would say no.

Static linking cannot happen with proprietary software, and based on your comment, your project is not open sourceable.

That being said, you seem to have your own wrapper anyway, and Qt keeps binary compatibility for a given major version the lifecycle of which is usually several years, so I would personally go for dynamic linking and some kind of binding.

Comment: BTW, if your employer try to "publish", "sell", or "give" a statically linked Qt executable of a proprietary program, he is (probably, but IANAL) acting illegally, unless he bought the Qt license permitting him to do so.